# Mysql won't work

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and to everything Linux. Ever since I mistakenly formatted my window 8.1 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 I have been having migraine headaches, trying to resolve the problem and the solution I found online has not been helpful at all.

First of all, I installed mysql-server on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, but every time I tried running the command in the terminal using: `mysql -uroot` it gives me this error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have tried every suggestion I can find online and even on this platform, None seems to work. If I can find solution to this then another problem will be posted later.

Please I need this problem resolved.

Help appreciated in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Answer (score 2):

You can check if mysql is running via

```
sudo service mysql status
```

If you want to start it- use

```
sudo service mysql start
```

If you want to stop it again

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Usually the service starts itself after the installation of the related packages. So in case the service isn't running on your host after booting the machine i assume the service start isn't properly configured.

The following commands should fix this

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

In case you want to remove the autostart again run

```
sudo update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

or just uninstall the related packages if you have no further use for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still haven't worked after following your suggestions

Comment: Try to be more detailed in your responses. Is the service itself running?